# How do I access the exit code of a heroku one-off dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using heroku's platform API + the rendezvous client to execute a command and retrieve it's output + exit code.

```
def run_command(heroku_client, app_name, command)
  dyno = heroku_client.dyno.create(app_name, command: command, attach: true)

  rendezvous_url = dyno["attach_url"]

  rz = Rendezvous.new({
    input:StringIO.new,
    output:StringIO.new,
    url: rendezvous_url
  })

  rz.start # Blocks until the command completes

  rz.output.rewind
  rz.output.readlines.join
end
```

I can fetch the output just fine, as shown above. I can't find a way to access the exit code though. I tried fetching `dyno.info` from the API after the process has exited, but I get a `404`.

Comment: My workaround for now is to use `my_command; echo $?` and then parse out the exit code manually.

Comment: Just found a gem that does the same: https://github.com/glenngillen/heroku-exit-status/blob/master/lib/heroku/exit-status.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support retrieving exit codes from a one-off dyno. One way to achieve this would be to use `my_command; echo $?` and then parse out the exit code manually. [This gem](https://github.com/glenngillen/heroku-exit-status/blob/master/lib/heroku/exit-status.rb) has a plugin that does that.